# Adding directory to python PATH

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I'm trying to achieve this https://github.com/strycore/fakegir

As this page says:

> After inserting this package in your editor's python path, you will
>   get autocompletion for every PyGObject module! By default the package
>   is saved in ~/.cache/fakegir/.   This is the directory you want to add
>   to your Python PATH. Of course, you shouldn't put this package in your
>   global PYTHONPATH or your PyGObject applications will stop working
>   immediatly ;)

How do I achieve this with Sublime Text?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your python program/script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/var/mydirectory")
```